# Angular ng-controller seems doesnt work in routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an issue on coding an angularjs app.

let me give a digest about what I'm doing, I'm using a template that use angularjs, it uses ui router. My issue is, seems like I can call the controller but when I load the page, it doesnt show anything, here's the code I'm working.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="tableHead in tableHeads">
          <th>{{ tableHead.th }}</th>
    </tr>
```

yes it has the data-ng-class right here.

```
 <li data-ng-class="{open: $state.includes('app.apps')}">
  <a ui-sref="app.members">
    <i class="icon-user material-icons"></i>
    <span translate="menu.MEMBERS"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The routes in routes.js

```
//Members
  .state('app.members', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/members/members.html',
    resolve: {
      deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load('scripts/controllers/members.js');
      }]
    },
    title: 'Members'
  })
```

and the controller

```
'use strict';

function membersCtrl() {
var vm = this;
vm.dataMembers = {
    'ajax': 'data/datamembers-arrays.json'
};
vm.tableHeads = [
    { th: 'Date Created'},
    { th: 'Mobile'},
    { th: 'First Name'},
    { th: 'Last Name'},
    { th: 'User Type'},
    { th: 'Email'},
    { th: 'Unit#'},
    { th: 'Street'},
    { th: 'Postal Code'}
];
}
angular.module('app').controller('membersCtrl', membersCtrl);
```

The `{{ tableHeads.th }}` shows nothing but blank (with background), but no text.

[It got detected by chromedevtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0MUb.png)

[And shows no errors on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvE8a.png)

Thanks for the time to read! Please help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will completely solve your problem. But, I noticed a couple of fixes you need to put in. Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.

1) Specify the controller in the state configuration as follows:

```
.state('app.members', {
url: '/',
templateUrl: 'views/members/members.html',
resolve: {
  deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
    return $ocLazyLoad.load('scripts/controllers/members.js');
  }]
},
title: 'Members',
controller: 'membersCtrl',
controllerAs: 'memCtrl'
})
```

2) Next, note that you are setting tableHeads to vm and not $scope. So, you need to use the 'controller as' syntax. Note, in the snippet above, we mentioned `controllerAs: 'memCtrl'`. So, change your template as follows

```
<tr ng-repeat="tableHead in memCtrl.tableHeads">
      <th>{{ tableHead.th }}</th>
</tr>
```